# Several "SideBySide" errors in the event viewer (Windows XP SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, sp3, event-log

For some reason, my netbook continuously comes up with SideBySide errors in the event viewer under Computer Management. Is there some way to get rid of these errors? My netbook occasionally BSODs and looking back into the event viewer after, at least 8 SideBySide errors were logged prior to BSOD. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Netbook is a Samsung N120 with upgraded RAM to 2 GB.

EDIT: So, SideBySide errors have been resolved and apparently the BSOD isn't related. But I remember specifically, that last time I had a BSOD, it was due to an "unknown hard error." What causes that?

Comment: In the event viewer,right click on the error line and select "event properties". In the "general" tab, there'll be some more details, hopefully with an application name. Then try and problem solve through this program- uninstall and reinstall or whatever. Any good?

Comment: (1) Generate Activation Context failed for C:\Program Files\SAMSUNG\MagicKBD\SITSndMx.DLL. Reference error message: The operation completed successfully.

(2) Resolve Partial Assembly failed for Microsoft.VC90.MFC. Reference error message: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.

(3) Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.MFC could not be found and Last Error was The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.

Always appearing in that order in multiples of 3. Don't know what Microsoft.VC90.MFC is... help?

Comment: It's part of Microsoft's Visual Studio 2008 C++ runtime.   You can try downloading an updated version from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en or re-installing the program that is failing, which looks like some Samsung software.  These probably aren't related to your BSOD's though.

Comment: Wow. Weird seeing no errors now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to shf301 for the answer!

> It's part of Microsoft's Visual Studio 2008 C++ runtime. You can try downloading an updated version from microsoft.com/downloads/… or re-installing the program that is failing, which looks like some Samsung software. These probably aren't related to your BSOD's though. – shf301 Jan 9 at 17:36